# Почему не работает AJAX в данном примере?

Tags: javascript, ajax

У меня есть папка с тремя файлами : index.html, serVer.js, ajax_info.txt

Вот index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<div id="demo"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>

<button type="button" onclick="loadDoc()">Change Content</button>

<script>
function loadDoc() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "ajax_info.txt", true);
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Вот serVer.js :

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require('url');
var querystring = require('querystring');
var static = require('node-static');
var file = new static.Server('.');


function accept(req, res) {

  // если URL запроса /vote, то...
  if (req.url == '/ajax_info.txt') {
    // через 1.5 секунды ответить сообщением
    setTimeout(function() {
      alert('Ваш голос принят: ' + new Date());
    }, 2000);
  } else {
    // иначе считаем это запросом к обычному файлу и выводим его
    file.serve(req, res); // (если он есть)
  }

}


// ------ этот код запускает веб-сервер -------

if (!module.parent) {
  http.createServer(accept).listen(8080);
} else {
  exports.accept = accept;
}
```

Я пробовал полностью закомментировать файл serVer.js и ничего не происходило, тайм аут не работал.Почему? Я установил node-static в папку командой npm install node-static. При нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит, текст не меняется. Спасибо

UPD: Я перенес папку на MAMP - там заработало. Но timeOut все равно не работает. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: есть ли ошибки в консоли браузера? кроме того `alert` не отвечает сообщением

Comment: Потому, что вы вызываете `alert` на сервере. Это лишено смысла. Совсем.

Comment: @Grundy Нет, файл сервер вообще неактивен. Я его даже удалил - все работало. Как включить этот файл?

Comment: @DmitriySimushev Хорошо, а как сделать, что бы был смысл?Делал все по гайду, так что плохо пока что понимаю, что делать

Comment: что за _гайд_.?

Comment: @Grundy в основном это  w3school и learn.javascript. Собираю по крупицам код.

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, Гайды в помойку. Оба. Начинайте с азов клиент-серверного взаимодействия.

Comment: если по крупицам - это не _гайд_. Смотрите что происходить при нажатии кнопки: к консоли браузера и во вкладке network(сеть). Кроме того, если вы просто открываете `index.html` как обычный файл - то никакой связи с файлом  `serVer.js` нет. Что за МАМР в вопросе? Где смотрели что должно быть в  `serVer.js`? В том же месте должно было быть описание как его запустить

Comment: ну и внутри `setTimeout` должна была быть запись в `response` а не alert

Comment: @Grundy MAMP это локальный сервер. апач, мускуль, пых. Нет, я запуская папку на локальном сервере и все работает. Вообщем, наверное, закрою вопрос, сумбурный вопрос очень. Можно твой скайп?Если есть свободное время

Comment: @НикитаЩипилов, какая разница писать сумбурный запрос тут или в скайпе? :)

Comment: @Grundy в скайпе не минусуют)Да и по отдельности задавать вопросы легче

Comment: хорошие вопросы тоже не минусуют :) Да и в скайпе нет правила [be-nice](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) :-)

Comment: @Grundy ну ладно, ты непоколебим )